# In-App-Purchase for Website

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have an app to publish. I have registration page on my website & mobile app.

If a user registers the username, send to register mail.

After login the user can able to upload their product image to website. I have limit of 3 images for upload. After they purchase via paypal or another means, they can upload more than 3 images (From the website).

After installing the app, the user enters username and it displays the login user product image. If customer use their company username it displays only their product images. I didn't use any payment option in app. I used in website and display my product image to viewcontroller calling imageView. Is apple reject my app?

Comment: What is the rejection message from the Apple?

Comment: I didn't publish. Im going to publish

Comment: Is there user registration for image upload at mobile side or just at website side and user just need to login?

Comment: Image upload only in website. Just registration only in mobile side..After registration mail will send to user with login link..after going to website user can login and upload images

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple will not reject your app.

You can submit your app to the AppStore successfully.

Comment: I have registration button in  mobile device also

Comment: @user2674668 Ya its fine. It doesn't matter for submitting the app. You can submit the app.

Comment: @user2674668 After getting solution of issue, please accept the answer , so that other viewers can also use that solution for the same issue.

Comment: But some docs mentioned, apple won't allow this kind of app. can you check my app video:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z20w1A8qz3E

Comment: @user2674668 for what reasons Apple reject your app? I dont think so that your app contains such things that Apple will reject your app.

Comment: Im using payment in my website not inside app. But after payment done, the product images are displayed to customer with client ids.

Comment: @user2674668 Ok. then you can submit the app. No any issue will be there and Apple will not reject your app.